# Is it correct to say that virtually all CMS' have database abstraction

Tags: php, content-management-system

As a php learner, I have been experimenting with some of the smaller PHP CMS'.  All CMS' that I have used employ a database abstraction layer.

Am I correct in assuming that this would be a characteristic of just about all PHP CMS'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing inherently characteristic of a CMS is that it separates content from display. Where or how it stores that content is arbitrary. The mechanism for connecting to the data store is also of no consequence. What you might think of as a "traditional" database is common but by no means necessary - any data backing is a database of content - text files, XML, SimpleDb or Google App Engine, etc.

Comment: Thanks.  At this point, the db abstraction seems frustrating to me, and I thought I could find a smaller CMS that didn't use it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, all(or most) cars have 4 wheels. But it doesn't mean a 5 wheeler cannot be a car.

It makes sense for CMS to have data abstraction, it does not mean they MUST have.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's safe to say that *most* CMS' use a DAL, but there's probably some remote one you've never heard of that doesn't, so I wouldn't claim that *all* CMS' use one.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. It's a characteristic of good software design. The rule of thumb is: "Program to an interface, not an implementation".

I'd recommend getting the hang of a good db layer and pushing those frustrations to the back of your mind. Good software design takes discipline!

Maybe you might like to read up on some design patterns and principles. It will save you a lot of trouble later on: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern

Good luck in your learnings!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say so, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Content_Management_Systems#PHP_2) also seems to agree with me.

Comment: To clarify, I think the proof is the list of flat-file-based CMS'.

Comment: I guess the interpretation of "virtually all CMS" differs from mine. =P

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would agree.  The 2 major PHP CMS libraries (Drupal and Joomla) each have some form of database abstraction, [although Drupal's is pretty slim](http://api.drupal.org/api/group/database/6).  Joomla [looks like it might have a little more to it than Drupal](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/Database/JDatabase.html).

Answer (score 0):

A database abstraction layer is a characteristic of almost any web based application.

This is commonly used to accomplish Separation of Concerns:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns